# Can I use Google App Engine's memcache service alongside the newly released memorystore with Redis?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python, google-cloud-memorystore

I am interested in using Google's newly released memorystore with Redis for the new features on my app. However, I would still want my old code that use memcache to run without any changes. Is it possible to run memcache alongside memorystore? Or, would I have to completely migrate to memorystore to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Although it is recommended to [migrate](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/memcache-to-memorystore) from Python2 to Python3 and switch from Memcache to Memorystore solution you can still use both I believe.
You will need to setup VPC connector in order to be able to connect to Memorystore from App Engine and install required dependancies. The step-by-step process is described [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/migrate-to-python3/memcache-to-memorystore#setup_redis_db)